# How to enable press-and-hold accent character menu in text editors (i.e. Xcode)?

Tags: macos, xcode, internationalization

When I press and hold a key (i.e. <kbd>a</kbd>) in most programs (such as a web browser, Evernote, etc.) I see the accent character pop-up menu.

However, I do not see the pop-up in Xcode or Vim, and I would like to. In those programs, it just repeats the character.

How do I enable the menu for those types of programs?

Comment: Well, by closing and re-opening Xcode, the popup menu is working again. Perhaps that was just a bug in OSX. But in Vim, no I do not see the popup (nor have I ever).